# Iterating with custom plotting functions using `map` family

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, purrr

I've created a custom function that can plot histograms using the `ggplot2` package. I want to iterate over each column of a data frame to produce a histogram for each.

```r
library(tidyverse)

#Making function to facilitate variable iteration. Supply data frame and single variable name
histogram_fun = function(df = model_data, x = "variable_name") {
     ggplot(df, aes(x = .data[[x]] )) +
         geom_histogram() + 
         labs(x = x)
}
```

When I try `histogram_fun(gss_cat, "age")`, I get the expected histogram. However, if I wanted to iterate over the variables `year`, `age`, and `tvhours`, I try something like this, to no avail:

```r
gss_numeric <- gss_cat %>% select_if(is.numeric) %>% names
gss_numeric
#> [1] "year"    "age"     "tvhours"

gss_cat %>% select(gss_numeric) %>% map(histogram_fun(df = ., x = gss_numeric))
#> Can't convert a `gg/ggplot` object to function
```

How would I go about iterating over my selection properly using the `map` or `walk` functions?

<sup>Created on 2019-10-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option where we convert the string to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)
histogram_fun <- function(data, x ) {
  ggplot(data, aes(!! rlang::sym(x) )) +
     geom_histogram() + 
     labs(x = x)
}

gss_numeric <- c("mpg", "disp")
p1 <- map(gss_numeric, ~ histogram_fun(mtcars, .x))
library(ggpubr)
p1 <- map(gss_numeric, ~ histogram_fun(mtcars, .x))
ggarrange(p1[[1]], p1[[2]], ncol = 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the inclusion of the `ggpubr::ggarrange` code.